# Unale to create list with element value containing '-' in robot framework

Tags: robotframework

Unable to create list and iterate in for loop with element value containing '-' in robot framework

Example:

```
  @{w_message}=    Create List    ${"t-Expo"}    ${"n-yiko"}    ${"sf-git"}
    @{w_value}=    Create List    ${"30"}    ${"k1"}    ${"B-2"}     

    FOR    ${param}    IN    @{w_message}    
        FOR    ${number}    IN    @{w_value}
            Log ${param}               
        END
    END
```

Output:

```
Resolving variable '${"t-Expo"}' failed: Variable '${"t}' not found.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because robotframework is looking for variable with the specific name. If you want to create a list loose the variable decorator and make sure
to have double spaces in your code.

This example should work:

```
*** Test Cases ***   
Example
    @{w_message}=    Create List     "t-Expo"    "n-yiko"     "sf-git" 
    @{w_value}=     Create List     "30"    "k1"    "B-2"
    FOR    ${param}    IN    @{w_message}
    Log    ${param} 
    END
    FOR    ${number}    IN    @{w_value}
    Log    ${number}
    END
```

Comment: if you put quotes in the `Create List` statement, you'll end up with a list of values that include the quote marks.